# Decode php://input json

Tags: php, json, input

I have this text from `file_get_contents('php://input')`:

```
[{"email":"text@examlple.com","event":"processed","sg_event_id":"JJTr9qA","sg_message_id":"AjvX5L7IQeGOfxmJV-OCnw","smtp-id":"<AfxmJV-OCnw@ismon1.sendgrid.net>","timestamp":16813363}]
```

I need to get single element like email or event, but haven't been able to get `json_decode` and others to work.

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

How can I reference a single element in the json data?

Comment: One-line version if all you ever wanted to get was one value: `echo json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))[0]->email;` Wee! lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array, so, you need to get the first element:

```
$json = '[{"email":"text@examlple.com","event":"processed","sg_event_id":"JJTr9qA","sg_message_id":"AjvX5L7IQeGOfxmJV-OCnw","smtp-id":"<AfxmJV-OCnw@ismon1.sendgrid.net>","timestamp":16813363}]';

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj[0]->email; //output text@examlple.com
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go, here's a fully working answer:

```
<?php

$str = '[{"email":"text@examlple.com","event":"processed","sg_event_id":"JJTr9qA","sg_message_id":"AjvX5L7IQeGOfxmJV-OCnw","smtp-id":"<AfxmJV-OCnw@ismon1.sendgrid.net>","timestamp":16813363}]';

$obj = json_decode($str);

echo $obj[0]->email;
```

Comment: Since your answer is the same as one already posted before. Its etiquette to delete your answer (I did not downvote you though).